# What's iex's equivalent to rp?

Tags: elixir

In the erlang shell, you can avoid troublesome term truncation with `rp`. What's the most idiomatic way to do this in Elixir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the equivalent would be passing `limit: :infinity` to `Kernel.inspect` or `IO.inspect`:

```
iex(1)> inspect(Enum.to_list(1..100))
"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]"
iex(2)> inspect(Enum.to_list(1..100), limit: :infinity)
"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]"
```

You can use `IO.inspect(..., limit: :infinity)` to print the value instead of returning it.

Comment: I think IO.inspect prints **and** returns it, which is pretty handy for adding and removing logging without creating temp variables

Comment: Although, in that case, the return value is truncated, I just noticed, which is less than ideal. You have to do: `inspect(IO.inspect(List.duplicate("http://www.example.com", 100), limit: :infinity), limit: :infinity)`

Answer (score 2):

With `IO.inspect` / `Kernel.inspect` the pretty-printing (e.g. colors) are lost, I prefer to modify the IEx limits:

```
iex(1)> IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: :infinity, printable_limit: :infinity])
:ok
iex(2)> Enum.to_list(1..100)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82,
 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Because this is cumbersome to type (no tab completion), I have these functions in my `~/.iex.exs`:

```
defmodule IExHelpers do
  def set_inspect_limit(limit \\ 50, printable_limit \\ 4096) do
    IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: limit, printable_limit: printable_limit])
  end
  def unset_inspect_limit() do
    set_inspect_limit(:infinity, :infinity)
  end
end
```

Use like this:

```
iex(1)> IExHelpers.unset_inspect_limit()
:ok
iex(2)> Enum.to_list(1..100)                                                  
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82,
 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
iex(3)> IExHelpers.set_inspect_limit()                                        
:ok
iex(4)> Enum.to_list(1..100)          
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]
```